# Using 'match' to insert content into a div without overwriting all inner HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Someone got me into the idea of using 'match' to target a page with the body class of 'ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB' in order to populate a specific div on the page (container).

This solved my problem in the scenario where the div is empty but replaces all the content if there is HTML present.

How would I modify my JS to not replace the content but add the new snippet first followed by the existing content?

Thanks in advance.

```
$(function() {    // document ready
    var body = $(document.body);    // body element

    // If match and length then modify html
    if (body.attr('class').match(/ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB/).length > 0) {
        $('#container').html("<div><h1>Products</h1></div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you do it in such a contrived *order-specific* way? Just use several `hasClass` calls.

Comment: _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I modify my JS to not replace the content but add the new snippet first followed by the existing content?

You should be using `.prepend()` instead of `.html()` to append the content as first element:

```
if (body.attr('class').match(/ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB/).length > 0) {
    $('#container').prepend("<div><h1>Products</h1></div>");
}
```

Comment: @Milind Anantwar: While this corrected the immediate problem, I am sure you will agree this is not a good jQuery solution (compare to using `hasClass`), :)

Answer (score 0):

I would never use such a contrived *order-specific* way. Far easier to read if you just use several `hasClass` calls combined:

```
$(function() {    // document ready
    var $body = $(document.body);    // body element

    // If match
    if ($body.hasClass('ly_productdetails') && $body.hasClass("ProductDetails") && $body.hasClass("en") && $body.hasClass("en_GB") {
        $('#container').prepend("<div><h1>Products</h1></div>");
    }
});
```

As a Regex is inherently slower than most string operations, the speed difference is negligible (and it only happens once on page load).

...and of course (finally read your *actual* problem) you also need to `prepend` the content and not replace it :)

Comment: I hear you but I'm not familiar with this method so didn't consider it. Are you saying your method has a speed advantage? thanks

Comment: @Adam C: I am saying it will be no faster or slower so that you would never notice any difference, but *it is* a lot more legible :) `hasClass` is the commonly used jQuery function suited to this task.

Comment: Food for thought. Thanks :)